# Install older Version of Python on Mac via virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I need to install a certain package, for which the developers suggest `Python 3.5`, since they don't support `3.7` yet.
I am running `Mac OS Mojave 10.14.2` and my Python version is `3.7.1`.

I have come across methods to switch between `Python 2.x` and `3.x` using `Virtualenv`, such as below:

```
virtualenv -p python2 myenv

virtualenv -p python3 myenv
```

However, is it even possible to have a specific version of Python, that too one older than I have already installed on my system?

Comment: if you have anaconda installed just do `conda install python==3.5`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have conda installed on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple versions of Python installed on OSX. Each one installs to a different path. You can't have multiple 'python3' executables in your path -- but if you use the absolute path then it'll work out fine.

You can go download the OSX version of Python 3.5 (which will install itself as python3.5 somewhere), and then create a virtualenv via

```
virtualenv -p /absolute/path/to/python3.5 myenv
```

Comment: Thank you...I see a .pkg file for `Python 3.5` on Python.org. Will installing 3.5 not interfere with my existing 3.7 installation? I thought one could isolate different installations of Python using Virtualenv.

Comment: @user2762934 not it won't as long as you ensure your $PATH environment variable contains the path to only 1 python major version per command (`python` for python2 and `python3`)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`python -m virtualenv <env_name> --python=<full-path-to-python-exectuable-file-and-exe-file>`

here `<full-path-to-python-exectuable-file-and-exe-file>` add python3.5 which you have downloaded